# How to pass object from PlayPlugin

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am writing a PlayPlugin. In the rawInvocation(request, response) method I create an object that I want all controllers to have access to. What would be the preferred way to achieve that? Each user will have their own object. It seems the Play session has not been created yet, so I cannot store it there. 
Thanks

Christian Güldner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a global filter using your plugin then it's better to overwrite `PlayPlugin.beforeActionInvocation` method:

```
public class MyPlugin extends PlayPlugin{
  @override public void beforeActionInvocation(Method actionMethod) {
     Object myObject = ...
     Http.Request.current().args.put("myobject", myObject);
  }
}
```

And in anyone of your controller you can get the object by:

Object myObject = `Http.Request.current().args.get("myobject")`

Comment: Thanks. I am using rawInvocation because my plugin handles authentification (ntlm). I am able to set the object (username) in the request args. But, the object being the username I want it set on the session. Maybe I can pick it up later in the flow and move it from request args to the session. I'll research some more.

Comment: So you are trying to create a plugin support active directory authentication? I got a module(https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-aaa) working for that. Check https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-aaa/blob/master/src/play/modules/aaa/utils/LdapAuthenticator.java and https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-aaa/blob/master/src/play/modules/aaa/morphia/Account.java to see how  it works. The problem of this module is there is no JPA impl right now coz I mainly use mongodb in my daily projects and it lacks document. But anyway you can refer to the source code

Comment: Had a quick look. Very impressive. The approach is different than what I am trying to achieve, which is simply SSO using ntlm.
Allow me to say, for all the work you put into the module, it's a pity you haven't spent just 30 minutes on explaining what the module does and how to use it.

Comment: Shame on me. Created the module for more than 1 year and just haven't found any time on doc, sample and JPA impl. Maybe I should ask help for some people who willing to contribute :)

Comment: Hey guldner, I am very interested in sso ntml but have had the chance to look into it yet. Any chance you might publish it as a module?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best or recommended way but you could always add it to the request.param

Comment: Thanks. It seems adding it to the request params is not allowed. Adding it to the request args, as suggested by green, worked for me.